# I have written this program in c using the hill cipher but the encryption and decryption output are always wrong

Tags: c

I have an assignment to write a program using the Hill Cipher. The program needs to both encrypt and decrypt but not run at the same time. To run the encrypt the user must enter "./hill -e" on the command line and "./hill -d" for decrypt. The program must prompt for and read an integer key from the user for a 2X2 matrix. It must also verify that the key is valid by checking the determinant. The inverse of this matrix must also be calculated. The user is then prompted to enter 2 characters for the plaintext and those are then changed to integers. After this is when the program will prompt the encryption or decryption.

There are no errors when compiling. Creating the matrix, checking the determinant, calculating the inverse, and changing the characters to the correct integer all work exactly as expected. My issue is I'm not getting the correct output for the encryption or decryption. I have tried several different variations but none work. Would someone be willing to point out the errors?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>


int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

    int i,j,k;

    int matrix[2][2],adjoint[2][2],plaintxt[2][0],encrypted[2][0],decrypted[2][0];

    long determinant;

    float inverse_matrix[2][2];

    char msg[10];

    printf("\nEnter your elements for a 2X2 matrix key.Each integer should be separated by a space.\n");

    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("\nThe 2X2 Key Matrix:\n");

    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }


    determinant = matrix[0][0]*matrix[1][1] - matrix[1][0]*matrix[0][1];

    if(determinant == 0)
    {
        printf("\nInvalid key. The matrix does not have an inverse.\n");
        printf("\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    adjoint[0][0] = matrix[1][1];
    adjoint[1][1] = matrix[0][0];
    adjoint[0][1] = -matrix[0][1];
    adjoint[1][0] = -matrix[1][0];

    printf("\nInverse of the 2X2 Key Matrix:\n");

    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            inverse_matrix[i][j] = (adjoint[i][j])/(float)determinant;
            printf("%lf\t", inverse_matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }


    printf("\n Enter 2 plaintext characters to cipher.\n");
    scanf("%s", msg);

    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        plaintxt[i][0] = msg[i] - 97;
        printf("%d", plaintxt[i][0]);
    }

    if(argc >= 2)
    {
        if(strcmp(argv[1], "-e") == 0)
        {
            for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
                k = 0;
                for(j = 0; j < 2; j++){
                    k = k + matrix[i][j] * plaintxt[i][0];
                }
                encrypted[i][0] = k % 26;
            }
            printf("\nEncrypted cipher text: ");
            for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                printf("%c", encrypted[i][0] + 97);
        }
        else if(strcmp(argv[1], "-d") == 0)
        {
            for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
                k = 0;
                for(j = 0; j < 2; j++){
                    k = k + inverse_matrix[i][j] * encrypted[i][0];
                }
                plaintxt[i][0] = k % 26;
            }
            printf("\nDecrypted cipher text: ");
            for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                printf("%c", plaintxt[i][0] + 97);
        }
    }
    
    return 0;}
```

Comment: It's very helpful to reduce your program to a non-interactive test case (input, output) along with expected output.  As is, you need to tell us what input you gave, what output you got and expected.  This may lead you to introduce some functions which would improve your program.

Comment: When you decrypt (-d) the `encrypted` variable is not initialized.

Comment: It's a good idea to parse the arguments first so we don't ask for a bunch of data, and then not being to anything with once we get it.

Comment: Lots of code. Do some work yourself, to create [mcve]. This is not quite "minimal".

Comment: Other hints: turn on compuler warnings. Define variables in smallest possible scope, one variable öer definition, and initialize them as you define them. Create functions.

Comment: Just what do you think having three 2-row 0-column arrays does for you? `plaintxt[2][0],encrypted[2][0],decrypted[2][0]`. Isn't it true that `"ISO C forbids zero-size array"`?? An *array-of-zero-sized-arrays* is no better. The minimum array size in C needed to hold a string of `nchar` is `nchar + 1` (the `+ 1` for the nul-terminating character)

Comment: You have a number of problems with encrypt/decrypt. (1) `plaintxt` and `encrypted` must be filled before your `for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)` loop. (when `-d` is given, `encrypted` is never set). (2) Your matrix multiplication is wrong. You have `i` where `j` belongs. Should be `k = k + matrix[i][j] * plaintxt[j][0];` and `k = k + inverse_matrix[i][j] * encrypted[j][0];`.  (3) you must be consistent in your use of zero-based `% 26`, e.g. `plaintxt[0][0] = tolower(msg[0]) - 'a';` and `plaintxt[1][0] = tolower(msg[1]) - 'a';` (same for `encrypted`).

Comment: Additionally, your matrix and inverse must be `% 26` (`fmodf()` for inverse). See [Hill cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_cipher) for your reference. Fixing those issue and adding VALIDATION for every `scanf()` allows your code to work, e.g. `1 2 3 4` with `"ab"` yields `encrypted` `"ce"` and then deciphering `"ce"` with the same matrix yields `"ab"` again. You also must provide columns for `plaintxt` and `encrypted`, using `[2][2]` is fine.  (or `[2][1]` for minimum)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from my comments, you have a large number of logic errors in your implementation of the [Hill cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_cipher). Specifically, the primary issues are:

1. C does not allow zero-size arrays. A 2D array is an array-of-arrays. You have `[2][0]` for both `plaintxt` and `encrypted` -- which is just a 2D array of zero-size arrays. Minimum you need `[2][1]` (or `[2][2]` is fine),
2. you never initialize `encrypted` if `"-d"` is given on the command line,
3. you must fully fill `plaintxt` and `encrypted` BEFORE you calculate the result of your matrix multiplication. Computing each encrypted/plaintxt character requires both of the original characters be in `plaintxt` or `encrypted`, respectively,
4. your matrix multiplication with the character vector is wrong. You have `i` in the vector where you should have `j`, e.g. `k = k + matrix[i][j] * plaintxt[j][0];` and `k = k + inverse_matrix[i][j] * encrypted[j][0];`,
5. both your `matrix` and `inverse` values must be `mod(26)` as well as your vector formed by the entered 2-character input. You seem to want to use lowercase characters, so be consistent and convert the input to lowercase and subtract `'a'` for the needed zero-based vector,
6. you must VALIDATE every user-input by ***checking the return*** of whatever input function you use.

There are a number of additional small issues noted with comments in the code below, but putting everything together and using `fgets()` to read the string-input (after emptying `stdin` of the `'\n'` left by `scanf()`), you could do something like the following:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

/* quick helper-function to empty stdin */
void empty_stdin (void)
{
  int c = getchar();
  
  while (c != '\n' && c != EOF) {
    c = getchar();
  }
}

int main (int argc, char * argv[]){

    int i,j,k;

    int matrix[2][2],
        adjoint[2][2],
        plaintxt[2][2] = {{0},{0}},   /* initialize your text arrays */
        encrypted[2][2] = {{0},{0}};

    long determinant;

    float inverse_matrix[2][2];

    char msg[1024];   /* don't SKIMP on buffer size */

    /* avoid long strings, split them, puts() is fine for no converisons */
    puts ("\nEnter your elements for a 2X2 matrix key."
          "Each integer should be separated by a space.");

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            /* validate EVERY input */
            if (scanf ("%d", &matrix[i][j]) != 1) {
                fputs ("invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
                return 1;
            }
            matrix[i][j] %= 26;   /* matrix must be % 26 */
        }
    }
    empty_stdin();    /* get rid of chars + '\n' remaining in stdin */
    
    puts ("\nThe 2X2 Key Matrix:");

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        putchar ('\n');   /* you putchar() a single-character */
    }


    determinant = matrix[0][0] * matrix[1][1] - matrix[1][0] * matrix[0][1];

    if (determinant == 0)
    {
        /* error output goes to stderr */
        fputs ("\nInvalid key. The matrix does not have an inverse.\n", 
               stderr);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    adjoint[0][0] = matrix[1][1];
    adjoint[1][1] = matrix[0][0];
    adjoint[0][1] = -matrix[0][1];
    adjoint[1][0] = -matrix[1][0];

    puts ("\nInverse of the 2X2 Key Matrix:");

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            /* inverse matrix must be % 26 as well */
            inverse_matrix[i][j] = fmodf ((adjoint[i][j])/(float)determinant,
                                          26.);
            printf ("%lf\t", inverse_matrix[i][j]);
        }
        putchar ('\n');
    }

    if (argc >= 2)
    {
        if (strcmp(argv[1], "-e") == 0)
        {
            /* move prompt and read into proper block */
            fputs ("\nenter 2 plaintext chars to encipher: ", stdout);
            /* should read/validate all user input with fgets */
            if (!fgets (msg, sizeof msg, stdin)) {
                puts ("(user canceled input)");
                return 0;
            }
            
            /* simply assign plaintxt before loop, zero-based for cipher */
            plaintxt[0][0] = tolower(msg[0]) - 'a';
            plaintxt[1][0] = tolower(msg[1]) - 'a';
            
            /* ensure you don't read beyond end of msg */
            for (i = 0; msg[i] && i < 2; i++){
                k = 0;
                for(j = 0; j < 2; j++){
                    k = k + matrix[i][j] * plaintxt[j][0];
                }
                encrypted[i][0] = k % 26;
            }
            /* should exit if i != 2 here */
            
            printf("\nEncrypted cipher text: ");
            for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                putchar (encrypted[i][0] + 'a');
            putchar ('\n');
        }
        else if (strcmp(argv[1], "-d") == 0)
        {
            /* move prompt and read into proper block */
            fputs ("\nenter 2 enciphered chars to decipher: ", stdout);
            /* should read/validate all user input with fgets */
            if (!fgets (msg, sizeof msg, stdin)) {
                puts ("(user canceled input)");
                return 0;
            }
            
            /* simply assign encrypted before loop, zero-based for cipher */
            encrypted[0][0] = tolower(msg[0]) - 'a';
            encrypted[1][0] = tolower(msg[1]) - 'a';
            
            /* ensure you don't read beyond end of msg */
            for (i = 0; msg[i] && i < 2; i++){
                k = 0;
                for(j = 0; j < 2; j++){
                    k = k + inverse_matrix[i][j] * encrypted[j][0];
                }
                plaintxt[i][0] = k % 26;
            }
            /* should exit if i != 2 here */
            
            printf("\nDecrypted cipher text: ");
            for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                putchar (plaintxt[i][0] + 'a');
            putchar ('\n');
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** these are minimal changes to make your code work, not an optimal rewrite of your code -- that is left to you)

**Example Use/Output**

Using the simple test-case where the matrix is formed by `1 2 3 4` and the string input of `"ab"` the code enciphers and deciphers as desired, e.g.

```
$ ./bin/hillcipher -e

Enter your elements for a 2X2 matrix key.Each integer should be separated by a space.
1 2 3 4

The 2X2 Key Matrix:
1       2
3       4

Inverse of the 2X2 Key Matrix:
-2.000000       1.000000
1.500000        -0.500000

enter 2 plaintext chars to encipher: ab

Encrypted cipher text: ce
```

And the decipher:

```
$ ./bin/hillcipher -d

Enter your elements for a 2X2 matrix key.Each integer should be separated by a space.
1 2 3 4

The 2X2 Key Matrix:
1       2
3       4

Inverse of the 2X2 Key Matrix:
-2.000000       1.000000
1.500000        -0.500000

enter 2 enciphered chars to decipher: ce

Decrypted cipher text: ab
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Thank you so much! All of the comments are very helpful. I had no idea the matrix and inverse needed to be mod26 as well. The other comments seem obvious now. I used the [2][0] so they would only be represented as a row matrix. I see why that is done later in the code and not at initialization. I was using the same key matrix as your output. The output for the encryption and decryption was always a double of a random letter (aa or yy) and it changed every time. I do understand why that is now. Again, thank you for your help. @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: @KadieWebb You are very welcome. Good luck with your coding. When you run into issues like this, it's often hard to see the forest for the trees -- so to speak. Best approach is to take a break and start-over. Pull the technical docs on whatever you are attempting to implement and write out how you would do it on paper. Then pickup the keyboard and code it. I used the wikipedia page and a calculator to confirm how it should go and then looked at the changes needed in your code. Sometimes that's a lot better approach than banging your head into a wall trying to make what you have work `:)`